# VBS - Not Working Script

Tags: vbscript

I have this VBScript that doesn't work. When I press "Yes" on the pop-up it says error. Please help. Thanks!

Code:

```
result = MsgBox ("Yes or No?", vbYesNo, "Start Web")

Select Case result
 Case vbYes
    shell.CurrentDirectory = "My Directory"
    shell.Run "startweb.bat"
 Case vbNo
End Select
```

When I Press "Yes" A .Bat file called: `startweb`

Comment: It just says "error"? Is `shell` defined? I assume "My directory" is just a fakey for Stackoverflow too, and is the full path to the bat file, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **When I press "Yes" on the pop-up it says error.**

What error?

- `Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required`, or
- `The system cannot find the file specified`, or
- something else?

**Solution**:

Case ˙Object required`:

```
Set Shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")       ''' add this line

result = MsgBox ("Yes or No?", vbYesNo, "Start Web")

Select Case result
    Case vbYes
        shell.CurrentDirectory = "My Directory"
        shell.Run "startweb.bat"
    Case vbNo
End Select
```

Case *file missing*: use fully qualified path to `"My Directory"`, e.g. `"c:\tests\My Directory"`

Case *Else*: unsolvable; [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44078123/edit) your question and add more info.

Comment: I'll mark yours right but I already fixed mine. I thought the post was deleted so  didn't check back. Here how i fixed it: `result = MsgBox ("Start School Streaming?", vbYesNo, "Start School Pop-Up")

Select Case result
Case vbYes
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    objShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Users\Kiril\Desktop\Codes\EXTRA"

    objShell.Run "startweb.bat"
Case vbNo
End Select`